# How do I create an email template?

Tags: civimail

I currently send a 'thank you for renewing' email out on an individual basis. I know there is a function for designing a template so I don't need to copy and paste text from Word, but I can't find the option. I would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can find them by going to **Mailings > Message Templates** OR **Administer > Communications > Message Templates** in the menu.

Here is the documentation: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/email/message-templates/